# problems with cursor and getting data?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a table and trying to fetch data from it using a cursor as follow:

```
public Cursor getcontent() {
    Cursor d = database.query(DatabaseHandler.Table_Name2,allColumns,selection, null, null,null,null); 
    return d;
}
Cursor r = X.getcontent();
if (r.getCount() > 0) {
    r.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String id = r.getString(r.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
        al.add(id);
        MainActivity.tt1.append("\n");  
        MainActivity.tt1.append(id);   
    } while (r.moveToNext()==true);
        r.close();
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG"," No value found");
    }      
}
```

I am showing the result in the `TextView` to see what data it is fetched. My problem is when I run this code sometimes it shows the data in the `TextView`, whatever it has fetched and sometimes it doesn't. Its a 50:50 ratio, according to me it should show fetched values every time as data is fetched every time I don't know what is wrong here, can someone tell me what's the issue here?

Comment: Did you debug the code , does it always come in the if statement above where you check size of cursor.

Comment: make sure the getContent is not returning null. rather than checking r.getCount() call r.moveToFirst() and then use r.isAfterLast == true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Whether Cursor you are getting  is Null or not . and if yes then What is the Count of Cursor. you can Do it by Below Way.

```
Cursor r = X.getcontent();
if ((r != null) && (r.getCount() > 0)) {
    r.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String id = r.getString(r.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
        al.add(id);
        MainActivity.tt1.append("\n");  
        MainActivity.tt1.append(id);   
    } while (r.moveToNext());
    r.close();
} else {
    Log.i("TAG"," No value found inside Cursor");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
Cursor r = X.getcontent();
try {
    if (r.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = r.getString(r.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
            al.add(id);
            MainActivity.tt1.append("\n");  
            MainActivity.tt1.append(id); 
        } while (r.moveToNext());
    }
} finally {
    if(r!=null) {
        r.close();
    }
}
```